# custom selectedBackgroundView outbound in UITableView Style Grouped

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]
After use UITableView Style Grouped, it have a problem when use selectedBackgroundView with custom color.

it draw outside of there UITableViewCell. 
Is it possible to clip them in bound  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problems and didn't find any simple and easy method to solve. I maked category for UIImage and used several images for catch all cases.

- single_cell_bg.png - image with all rounded corners
- top_cell_bg - image with rounded top corners
- .....

not so elegant but working

```
@interface UIImage (CellBacground)
- (UIImage *)backgroundCellViewforRow:(NSInteger)row totalRow:(NSInteger)total;
@end



#import "UIImage+CellBacground.h"

@implementation UIImage (CellBacground)

- (UIImage *)backgroundCellViewforRow:(NSInteger)row totalRow:(NSInteger)total {
    NSString *path = NULL;
    if (row == 0) {
        if(total == 1) {
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"single_cell_bg" ofType:@"png"];
        } else {
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"top_cell_bg" ofType:@"png"];
        }
    } else {
        if ((total - row) == 1) {
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bottom_cell_bg" ofType:@"png"];
        } else {
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"middle_cell_bg" ofType:@"png"];
        }
    }
    UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIEdgeInsets imInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    UIImage *strImage = [theImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:imInset];
    return strImage;
}
@end
```

Call in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[backImage backgroundCellViewforRow:indexPath.row totalRow:[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]];
UIImageView *backview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backImage];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = backview;
```

Comment: Thank you Darktau, i think this is the best solution now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a real solution that doesn't use images and that should work in every situation.  It is a bit tricky due to an issue with tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: on the iPad only (see comment).  Besides that, once you know how to round individual corners things fall into place fairly naturally.

The controller has be the one to round the corners because it is the one that knows what position the cell is in (first, last, etc) and that affects which corners are rounded.  The best place to do the rounding seems to be in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:.  The following is an example UITableViewController subclass:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)installSelectedBackgroundView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // choose a color or add a gradient, etc
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1; // optional border
    view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = view;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self installSelectedBackgroundView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self installSelectedBackgroundView];
}

@end

@implementation MainViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

+ (void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners forView:(UIView *)view {
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}

+ (void)roundCornersForSelectedBackgroundViewForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger rows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    if (rows == 1) {
        [[self class] roundCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners forView:cell.selectedBackgroundView];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [[self class] roundCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight forView:cell.selectedBackgroundView];
    } else if (indexPath.row == rows-1) {
        [[self class] roundCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight forView:cell.selectedBackgroundView];
    } else {
        [[self class] roundCorners:0 forView:cell.selectedBackgroundView];
    }
}

+ (void)deferredRoundCornersForSelectedBackgroundViewForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [[self class] roundCornersForSelectedBackgroundViewForTableView:tableView cell:cell indexPath:indexPath];
    });
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // cell.selectedBackgroundView.frame is not sized correctly yet, so rounding the corners has to be deferred briefly
    [[self class] deferredRoundCornersForSelectedBackgroundViewForTableView:tableView cell:cell indexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

UIView *myCellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

myCellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1];

cell.selectedBackgroundView = myCellView;

[myCellView release];